# Probabilities in a Set of numbers

Tags: probability

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}.$ Three subsets $A,$ $B,$ $C$ of $S$ are chosen at random.

(a) Find the probability that $A \cup B \cup C = S.$

(b) Find the probability that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C.$

Here is what I have for Part (a) so far:

For the equality to be false, there must be some element in S that is not in A or B or C. And for each element, there is a probability of 1/2 that it is in a given subset. It can be put into the subset, or it can be left out. So, for each element, there is a 1/8 chance it is not in any of the 3 subsets.

I'm stuck on how to continue and I have no idea how to do part b.

Comment: The subsets are chosen independently and uniformly at random from $\mathcal{P}(S)$?

Comment: The subsets are chosen randomly from the set, {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n}.

Comment: "*randomly*" is not specific enough

Comment: any integer(s) can be chosen from S to be part of A, B, and C.

Comment: So does each possibility for $A$ have probability $\frac1{2^n}$? And and for $A,B,C$ a probability of $\frac1{2^{3n}}$?

Comment: @henry yes, it does

Comment: */facepalm*... To emphasize how important being perfectly clear in what way things are randomly selected and why just saying "randomly" is not good enough, please visit the page for [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) where depending on in what way "randomly" is meant to be interpreted you get wildly different answers for a problem.

Comment: Now that we finally have that out of the way... a hint for (b)... for $A\subseteq B\subseteq C\subseteq S$ to be true, we can unambiguously assign each element of $S$ a number from $0,1,2,3$ based on the number of the sets $A,B,C$ the element is an element of.  And looking at such an assignment we can get back the original sets $A,B,C$

Comment: For (a) you want the probability that each element is in one of the three sets.  For one element this is $1-\frac18=\frac78$

Comment: @henry How did you get 1/8?

Comment: @kquinn the same way as you... $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: @kquinn you said "So, for each element, there is a 1/8 chance it is not in any of the 3 subsets."

Comment: So for part (a) it would just be (7/8)^n since there are n numbers in S?

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good start on (a)- every element has a $\frac78$ chance of being covered. These events are independent so the probability every element is covered is $(\frac78)^n$.

You can do (b) similarly. In order to satisfy the condition, each element needs to be either in none of the sets, in $C$ only, in $B$ and $C$, or in all of them. What is the probability of this for each element?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for part $b$. (SPOILERS)

To choose $A,B,C \subseteq S$ such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$, you can use this method:

-choose $c \in [\![0,n]\!]$ the cardinal of $C$
-choose the elements of $C$
-choose $b\in [\![0,c]\!]$ the cardinal of $B$
-choose the elements of $B$
-choose $a\in [\![0,b]\!]$ the cardinal of $A$
-choose the elements of $A$

And this uniquely determines $A,B,C$. Therefore, the total number of triplets $(A,B,C)$ of subsets of $S$ verifying $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ is

$$
\sum_{c=0}^n  {n\choose{c}} \sum_{b=0}^c  {c\choose{b}} \sum_{a=0}^n  {b\choose{a}}
= \sum_{c=0}^n  {n\choose{c}} \sum_{b=0}^c  {c\choose{b}} 2^b
= \sum_{c=0}^n  {n\choose{c}} \underbrace{\sum_{b=0}^c  {c\choose{b}} 2^b}_{(1+2)^c = 3^c}
= \sum_{c=0}^n  {n\choose{c}} 3^b = 4^n
$$

Comment: Use my hint above for an immediate way of arriving at $4^n$ not relying on such messy summations.

Comment: Your hint probably saves a bit of time but I think the method I suggested should be at least looked upon because such 'constructive' methods occur in a lot of counting problems and should be known in my opinion. But of course, the more solutions for a problem the better and your solution offers a nice view on the question! Moreover, I don't find the summations so nasty